# Encontrar item em uma List com método Contains

Tags: c#, lista, contains

Tenho um objeto do tipo Dado, que possui os atributos nome(string) e transacaBloqueio(int). Tenho uma List de Dado chamada dadosBloqueioCompartilhado.
Quero consultar se essa lista possui um item já com o mesmo nome e mesma transacaoBloqueio que o passado como parâmetro. Se não possuir adiciona, se possuir não adiciona.
Estou tentando usar o método contains, mas não está funcionando. Ela adiciona o item mesmo já tendo um igual. O que pode estar acontecendo?

Classe Dado

```
public class Dado
    {
        private string nome;
        private int transacaoBloqueio;

        public string getNome()
        {
            return this.nome;
        }

        public int getTransacaoBloqueio()
        {
            return this.transacaoBloqueio;
        }

        public void setNome(string nomeDado)
        {
            this.nome = nomeDado;
        }

        public void setTransacaoBloqueio(int transacao)
        {
            this.transacaoBloqueio = transacao;
        }
    }


private List<Dado> dadosBloqueioCompartilhado= new List<Dado>();
private Dado dadoAtual = new Dado();
dadoAtual.setNome('A');
dadoAtual.setTransacaoBloqueio(1);

if (!dadosBloqueioCompartilhado.Contains(dadoAtual))
{
    dadosBloqueioCompartilhado.Add(dadoAtual);
}
```

Comment: Coloque a classe dado e dadosBloqueioCompartilhado também por favor! Já adianto de anti mão assim realmente não funciona porque as classes são diferentes pela instâncias criadas! Terá que fazer de outra forma! porque você tem que testar o valor! mas, coloque as duas classes que eu to formulando uma resposta

Comment: @João Coloquei a classe Dado. A dadosBloqueioCompartilhado é uma List do tipo Dado.

Comment: eu já elaborei a resposta. Vou colocar uma observação sobre a sua classe, parece usar Java fazendo set e get como propriedade no mundo NET não é assim!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quando se cria um `classe` e um `lista dessa classe` e tenta verificar se um valor coexiste dentro dessa lista pode haver confusão no método [Contains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx) que verifica a instância da classe e não o valor em si das propriedades.

Exemplo:

***Class Dado***

```
public class Dado
{
   public string Nome { get; set; }
   public int TransacaoBloqueio { get; set; }
}
```

***Código 1:***

```
IList<Dado> dadosBloqueioCompartilhado = new List<Dado>();

Dado dadoAtual = new Dado();
dadoAtual.Nome = "A";
dadoAtual.TransacaoBloqueio = 1;

if (!dadosBloqueioCompartilhado.Contains(dadoAtual))
{
    dadosBloqueioCompartilhado.Add(dadoAtual);
}

if (!dadosBloqueioCompartilhado.Contains(dadoAtual))
{
    dadosBloqueioCompartilhado.Add(dadoAtual);
}
```

Nesse trecho de código o primeiro `if` vai deixar adicionar o item dentro da lista, já o segundo não, porque a instância da `classe` já existe dentro dessa lista é o método [Contains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx) verifica o objeto (a instancia) e não seus valores.

***Código 2:***

```
IList<Dado> dadosBloqueioCompartilhado = new List<Dado>();

Dado dadoAtual = new Dado();
dadoAtual.Nome = "A";
dadoAtual.TransacaoBloqueio = 1;

if (!dadosBloqueioCompartilhado.Contains(dadoAtual))
{
    dadosBloqueioCompartilhado.Add(dadoAtual);
}

dadoAtual = new Dado();
dadoAtual.Nome = "A";
dadoAtual.TransacaoBloqueio = 1;

if (!dadosBloqueioCompartilhado.Contains(dadoAtual))
{
    dadosBloqueioCompartilhado.Add(dadoAtual);
}
```

Nesse caso especifico você vai ter um surpresa indesejada, porque, a lista terá adicionado os dois itens, porque, suas instâncias são diferentes e o [Contains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx) nesse caso verifica as instâncias e não os valores.

***Código 3***

Solução aparente para verificar os dados contindos na classe:

Crie um classe implementando a interface [IEqualityComparer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms132151(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public class ComparerDados : IEqualityComparer<Dado>
{
    public bool Equals(Dado x, Dado y)
    {
        return (x.Nome.Equals(y.Nome)) &&
            (x.TransacaoBloqueio.Equals(y.TransacaoBloqueio));
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Dado obj)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

E com o código abaixo ele vai conferir os dados contidos na instância da classe com o método [Contains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx), verificando ai os valores contidos na instância da classe:

```
IList<Dado> dadosBloqueioCompartilhado = new List<Dado>();

Dado dadoAtual = new Dado();
dadoAtual.Nome = "A";
dadoAtual.TransacaoBloqueio = 1;

if (!dadosBloqueioCompartilhado.Contains(dadoAtual, new ComparerDados()))
{
    dadosBloqueioCompartilhado.Add(dadoAtual);
}

dadoAtual = new Dado();
dadoAtual.Nome = "A";
dadoAtual.TransacaoBloqueio = 1;

if (!dadosBloqueioCompartilhado.Contains(dadoAtual, new ComparerDados()))
{
    dadosBloqueioCompartilhado.Add(dadoAtual);
}
```

Nesse caso só vai ter um item na lista.

---

**Observação:** Nada impede você utilizar `setNome`, mas o ideal e padrão da arquitetura .NET é `public string Nome {get ;set; }` além de ser mais legivel é o padrão para todo e qualquer código. Exemplo se fizer do jeito `setNome` no `ORM Entity Framework` ele não vai considerar.

Comment: Perfeito! Testei e funcionou. Obrigado pela ajuda João. Ótima e esclarecedora resposta.

Comment: E se eu quiser retornar o dado que ele encontrou na lista? Como posso fazer?

Comment: Pode falar mais eu realmente não entendi. Fala assim o processo.?